# How to remove texts characters from the header tag

Tags: html, css, text, header, banner

I have a problem with my [new blog](http://www.grafobia.com). There are characters like this `-->` on the top header of the blog.
I don't understand where is that even though [inspected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed1kf.jpg) is just a text and I can't find it in the template to delete it ):

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: lines 2783 and 2788 of your html, they have closing comment tags without a oppening comment tag ``<-- comment -->``

Comment: yeah I don't get it , I looked for this comment tag but I can't find where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the --> from the beginning of the style tag line 2783

```
--></style>
<style id='template-skin-1' type='text/css'><!--
#outer-wrapper {
width:1200px
}
--></style>
```

Comment: I tried but there is no such as thing in this line , I tried to search by ( template-skin ) and this is what I found https://imgur.com/9yvVMuz  // https://imgur.com/mntG0dW

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your source, the problem is at the top of the "body" div; the characters `--&gt;` are causing that little arrow to display. If you have access to that from the template it should be easy to delete.

```
 <body class="index" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">- 
   -&gt;
    <style id="template-skin-1" type="text/css"><!--
    #outer-wrapper {
    width:1200px
    }
    --></style>
```

Comment: Well , I can't find this characters on the template. when I go to the body tag, there is nothing. furthermore , when I search by ( --> ) I find only comment tags , I can't find this comment which is not closed..https://imgur.com/a/3evMr

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all dear friend !

I don't know but I solved it ! I removed the line below and boom , I remember that I added it the day before to, I followed a tutorial to speed up loading time of the website , but I deleted everything later when I didn't work.
I don't know why this is the reason of the issue , but I'm glad I made it thanks to your help.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBqFd.jpg
thank you all.